# Is export in bash alias of eval function which many other scripts have?

Tags: bash, export

I don't have much experience with `export` but it gives me the impression that it's quite similar with `eval`.

Am I wrong or not?

Answer (score 1):

Normally variables assigned to are only available to the current shell process. `export` makes sure that child processes have the environment variable set as well.

```
foo=123
echo "$foo"
bash -c 'echo "$foo"'
export foo=123
echo "$foo"
bash -c 'echo "$foo"'
```